# Wrap/remove span around a textarea value if regExp !match

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, textarea

I want the same functionality that can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/wT2eL8/2).

I need a directive that loops over the array that is displayed within the textare/highlighter and compares if the value matches the following regExp(integers, floats and scientific notation both positive and negative values):

```
/-?\d+[\.,]?\d*[eE]?-?\d*/g
```

If it matches there will be no span around that element in the "highlighter" div, otherwise it will be wrapped in a "span" and therefore highlighted in red.

Best approach?

[image]

Template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="form_field_float">
  <div>
    <div class="highlighter" id="mirror">
      <p ng-repeat=" x in dbo.attributes[attobj.name]"><span>{{ x }}</span></p>
    </div>
    <textarea id="textarea" rows="{{dbo.attributes[attobj.name].length + 2}}" ng-model="dbo.attributes[attobj.name]" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
  </div>
</script>
```

CSS:

```
  .highlighter, #textarea {
      width: 400px;
      height: 300px;
      font-size: 10pt;
      font-family: 'verdana';
  }

  .highlighter p {
      font-size: 10pt;
      font-family: 'verdana';
      margin:0 0 0 0;
  }


  .highlighter {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 1px;
      margin-left: 1px;
      color: white;

  }

  .highlighter span {

      color: red;
      background: red;
      opacity:.4;
  }

  #textarea {
      position: relative;
      background-color: transparent;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok my brain finally came around and found a solution:

[image]

Template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="form_field_float">
  <div spellcheck="false">
    <div class="highlighter" id="mirror">
      <div ng-repeat=" x in dbo.attributes[attobj.name] track by $index" ng-controller="textVal">
        <div ng-if="!check(x)"><span>{{ x }}</span></div>
        <div ng-if="check(x)">{{ x }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea id="textarea" rows="{{dbo.attributes[attobj.name].length + 2}}" ng-model="dbo.attributes[attobj.name]" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
  </div>
</script>
```

Controller:

```
   app.controller('textVal', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {      
             $scope.check = function(valueToCheck){
                if(!isNaN(valueToCheck)){
                  return true;
                } else{ return false;}
             }
        }
   ]);
```

CSS:

```
  .highlighter, #textarea {
      width: 100%; 
  }



  .highlighter {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 1px;
      margin-left: 1px;
      color: white;

  }

  .highlighter span {

      color: red;
      background: red;
      opacity:.4;
  }

  #textarea {
      position: relative;
      background-color: transparent;
  }
```

**STILL HAVE ONE ISSUE MAYBE SOMEONE CAN GIVE ME A NICE CLEAN SOLUTION FOR!!!:**
"If enter is pressed, no value is typed and enter is pressed again, an offset will occur between the textarea value and the highlighter-div":

[image]

Comment: The copy paste problem is solved by using "track by $index" in ng-repeat i was duplicating entries when copying within the textarea or same values from excel pasted multiple times consecutively.